# Firefox Profile cannot be loaded in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm learning to create an automation script using the Robot Framework. I am using Ubuntu 22.04 OS. I want to automate the web [www.carvago.com](http://www.carvago.com) to do a car search. I've imported RPA.Browser Library, and made Search Car keywords where there are steps for Open Available Browser. When I am run the script, then show error "Your Firefox Profile cannot be loaded". Anybody can help me to fix this issue? Here I attach screenshoot of error and my code. Thank you.
[image: Error 1]
[image: Error 2]

```
    *** Settings ***
Documentation       Template robot main suite.

Library             Collections
Library             MyLibrary
Library             RPA.Browser.Selenium
Library             RPA.Excel.Files
Resource            keywords.robot
Variables           MyVariables.py

*** Variables *** 
${Browser}          Chrome
${SiteUrl}          https://carvago.com/

*** Keywords ***
Create Excel Report
    Create Workbook     /home/maaofficial/Documents/test_report_2.xlsx
    Save Workbook


Read Excel
    Open Workbook       /home/maaofficial/Documents/test_escape_list.xlsx
    ${list}     Read Worksheet      header=true
    Log To Console      ${list}
    Close Workbook
    FOR         ${index}    IN      @{list}
        Search Car      ${index}
    END

Search Car
    [Arguments]         ${index}
    Go To   ${SiteUrl}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Wait Until Element Is Visible       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]
    Press Keys      NONE    ${index}[make]
    Sleep   333ms
    Press Keys      NONE    TAB
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div
    Sleep   500ms
    Press Keys      NONE    ${index}[model]
    Sleep   333ms
    Press Keys      NONE    TAB
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/input
    Sleep   500ms
    Press Keys      NONE    ${index}[max_km]
    Sleep   500ms
    # Click Minimize Button
    Click Element                        xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]
    Sleep  333ms
    # Click Button Search
    Click Element                         xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div[1]/button
    # Click Sort by Button
    Wait Until Element Is Visible         xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div    10s
    Sleep   3s
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div
    Sleep   3s
    # Click Lowest Price
    Click Element                       xpath:/html/body/div[8]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[6]/p
    Sleep   3s

    # Get Text Element
    ${name}                 Get Text                xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div/div[2]/h6
    Sleep   2s
    ${total_km}             Get Text                xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]
    Sleep   2s
    ${seller}               Get Text                xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/span[2]
    Sleep   2s
    ${country}              Get Text                xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span
    Sleep   2s
    ${fuel}                 Get Text                xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[5]/span[2]
    Sleep   2s
    ${transmission}         Get Text                xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/span[2]
    Sleep   2s
    ${price}                Get Text                xpath:/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/a/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]
    Sleep   2s
    
    ${car_dict}     Create Dictionary
    ...         name=${name}
    ...         total_km=${total_km}
    ...         seller=${seller}
    ...         country=${country}
    ...         fuel=${fuel}
    ...         transmission=${transmission}
    ...         price=${price}
    Log To Console      ${car_dict}

    Append To Excel  ${car_dict}


Append To Excel
    [Arguments]                 ${car_dict}
    Open Workbook               /home/maaofficial/Documents/test_report.xlsx
    Append Rows To Worksheet    ${car_dict}     header=True
    Save Workbook


*** Tasks ***
Main
    Create Excel Report
    Open Available Browser      ${SiteUrl}      ${Browser}
    Read Excel
    Close Browser
```

Comment: Try using `Open Browser` with same arguments as with `Open Available Browser` and report back.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

1.Download updated geckodriver
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

```
tar -xvf geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz

chmod geckodriver
sudo mv ./geckodriver /usr/local/bin
/usr/local/bin$ geckodriver -V
```

geckodriver 0.31.0 (b617178ef491 2022-04-06 11:57 +0000)

- when installing from webdrivermanager, the webdrivermanager somehow installs v0.29(older)

2. Download firefox(directly from mozilla.org) - on Ubuntu is installed in sandboxed snap
   which will prompt - "Profile cannot be loaded/found" error

firefox-105.0.3.tar.bz2

uncompress and add symbolic link so that from command line, this downloaded version will be used

```
sudo ln -s  /home/akiss/Downloads/firefox/firefox /usr/local/bin/firefox
```

Comment: "_on Ubuntu is installed in sandboxed snap which will prompt - "Profile cannot be loaded/found" error_" was the moneyball for me, I think. Used the Store to install Firefox. Installed Chrome from `.deb` file and it's doing fine.